# list keeps showing null

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `List` object that uses `ArrayList` to store a `String` object. When I am attempt to use `list.add("a")` in the main method, it shows up as null. When I use `System.out.println(list.toString())` What did i do wrong?

```
class List
    {
      //Instance variables
      private String data;
      private ArrayList list;

      //Constructor
      public List()
      {
        this.list = new ArrayList();
      }
      public void add(String data)
      {
        list.add(data);
      }

      public String toString()
      {
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use another name instead of List because List is the in build class.

Comment: You should use `ArrayList<String>` instead of the raw type.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `data` member in your class, since you store the data inside the List. Since you don't use that member, is remains `null`, and you return that `null` in your `toString` method.

Change your `toString` method to return the `String` representation of the `ArrayList` :

```
  public String toString()
  {
    return list.toString();
  }
```

P.S. it would be better to rename your class, since `List` may hide `java.util.List` (even though you don't seem to use `java.util.List`, it's still a good idea not to re-use standard JDK class/interface names).

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind. Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

change your tostring() method to

```
  public String toString()
      {
        return list.toString();
      }
```

Comment: The same answer is already is provided above. What is new in this?